# Getting cat&sprintf output into code/function/calculations

Tags: r, printf

I am trying to automatically copy and paste the string names for route starting point and route endpoint (from GPX file) into the following statement:

```
dl$X1<-df[[1]][["Paris to Rome"]][["lon"]]
```

This is the manually written statement and works fine/perfect/correctly.

What I want is to extract "Paris to Rome" automatically from the GPX file. This also works fine, with following code:

```
 C<-Z[["waypoints"]][["name"]] 
    A<-cat(sprintf("\"%s %s %s\"\n", C[1],"to", C[2]))
    cat(sprintf("\"%s %s %s\"\n", C[1],"to", C[2]))
```

and the last statement returns "Paris to Rome"

But the problem is, when I substitute "Paris to Rome" (replace NR1 by NR2) with 
NR 1: `dl$X1<-df[[1]][["Paris to Rome"]][["lon"]]` replaced by 
NR 2: `dl$X1<-df[[1]][[cat(sprintf("\"%s %s %s\"\n", C[1],"to", C[2]))]][["lon"]]`
the specified column X1 of the DL dataset stays empty (while the lon coordinates are in it when the first statement ,NR1, is executed)
Any solutions?

The  automatisation is needed because I need to have the script work for any provided start and end point in any possible GPX file, in order that other people only to have to read in their GPX file before running the script I have written, without looking to my code.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your explanations are unclear. Why the name "Paris to Rome" in first line of your code (which I think you call NR1) does not contain quotes and new line character and in your second approach with cat(sprintf()) you use them? Why not to use something like df[[1]][[ sprintf("%s %s %s", C[1],"to", C[2])]][["lon"]] ?

Comment: The first line, where "Paris to Rome" is quoted between the squared brackets, is manually written and works fine. What I want is to automatically retrieve "Paris to Rome" from the file (which works fine by cat(sprintf) and put that output as input in dl$X1 and so on. But I don't succeed in automatically put the cat(sprintf) output with "Paris to Rome" between quotes as input in the dl$X1 function

Comment: to put it more simplistic :  with cat sprint I automatically extract an output from a file,  e.g. "Paris to Rome"  and wat I want, is provide EXACTLY THE SAME (including "  ") in ANOTHER function as INPUT!.  Logic seems to copy the Cat-SprintF function to the other INPUT, but this does not work and don't provides the same result as when the catsprintf statement is executed seperately!